# Rotating within a question in the iOS app messes up the question list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app

Here's a way to mess up the question list on the iPhone:

1. From a list of questions, tap to enter the question
2. Rotate your device
3. Return to the question list with the back chevron.

The question list spacing is all wrong for that rotation. This seems to occur whether you're in portrait or landscape to start.

I can reliably reproduce on App Store build 1.2.1, iOS 8.1.1 (12B435) on an iPhone 5s.

#### Screenshots

Starting from portrait:

[image]

Starting from landscape:

[image]

(The failed requests are because I’ve used up my data for the month, and have nothing to do with the SE app.)

Comment: Able to reproduce, taking a look at this...

Comment: That is an exemplary bug report, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the device rotation, we needed to recalculate the height of the cells. However, Since the rotation was happening offscreen, the view controller wasn't aware of this. We now handle this use case as well.

This will be fixed beginning **beta version 1.2.0.174.**

Comment: I just got release version 1.2.2, in which the bug is fixed for me.